# Site crashed from nowhere

Tags: php

Recently my friend's company site stopped working. He is using paid host. The site says only this:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function set_magic_quotes_runtime() in /home/inplan/www/root/includes/framework.php:21 Stack trace: #0 /home/inplan/www/root/index.php(22): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /home/inplan/www/root/includes/framework.php on line 21`

Comment: That function was deprecated over a decade ago, you shouldn't be using it. It was removed in PHP 8.0.

Comment: can u give me alternative ?

Comment: thats the code: https://pastebin.com/NCp3Cf72

Comment: Just get rid of it, it's not needed.

Comment: now it says:Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.

Comment: Your friend's hosting company updated the version of PHP on the server, likely because they don't want the security risk of running old versions - the [last version that included that function was 5.6](https://3v4l.org/26pvU), which [received its last official patch 3.5 years ago](https://www.php.net/eol.php). The code needs to be reviewed and updated to work on modern PHP, as there's likely to be more than just this one problem if the code has been untouched that long; if you and your friend don't know how, hire a contractor.